Can't check if jsonb key exists
I'm new to Postgres, I'm trying to check if a jsonb field key exists or not but my results seem wrong:
When I execute this line:
SELECT id, poll FROM joi_post WHERE NOT(poll ? 'ended');

I get a row with the poll field containing the ended key so it should not be returned. Here's an image of the results. The poll field value is:
"{\"choices\":[{\"content\":\"a\"},{\"content\":\"b\"}],\"ended\":\"1\"}"

And if I remove the NOT condition like this:
SELECT id, poll FROM joi_post WHERE poll ? 'ended';

then I get no results, even when the ended key is there and has a value of "1".
I would appreciate some help here :)
I'm trying to check if the poll field has an "ended" key, but I'm getting results when I shouldn't and the other way around. Also, when I run this code I get <null>:
SELECT poll->'ended' as ended FROM joi_post;

With MySQL it was simple as using JSON_EXTRACT(poll, '$.ended') but now I'm migrating to Postgres and I can't understand how come this doesn't work.

select '{"choices":[{"content":"a"},{"content":"b"}],"ended":"1"}'::jsonb ? 'ended'; t. Are sure poll is a jsonb field, what you show with all the escapes(\\) seems to indicate it is something else.

Found the issue, it appears Drizzle ORM is the problem here, as it's always saving strings to jsonb fields, see jsonb always inserted as a json string
The solution that worked for me was to cast the object (input.poll) to jsonb using the sql operator:
await ctx.db.insert(posts).values({
    // rest of the fields here
    poll: sql`${input.poll}::jsonb`
});

